# Skype online shows arabic letters in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, skype, chromium, google

When I try to use Skype online **web.skype.com** with google chrome or chromium browsers, it shows only arabic letters. How can I fix this?  [image]

Comment: And what about all other pages that you open, are they in english ?

Comment: The problem is only with the page web.skype.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the following link in a new tab

`chrome://settings/languages`

and under languages see whether Arabic is turned on somehow, if yes then remove it. Also turn on the **Auto translate** and try again. If none of that works try restoring setting to their original default (this option is available at the bottom).

If the last option doesn't work either please do right click on the page and click on the option of "Translate to English" (all along I'm assuming english is your preferred or default language).

Comment: It works with the right click and translating the page, thanks.